# Xamarin Forms Appcenter how to get installation ID

Tags: xamarin.forms, task, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to get the installation ID of the Appcenter to only send notifications to selected devices, but 
`string  installid = AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync().ToString();`

returns `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.Nullable1[System.Guid]]`

And `string  installid = AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync().Result.ToString();` returns empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/xamarin#identify-installations) states that you need to retrieve the installId as follows

```
System.Guid? installId = await AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync();
```

You need to await the call, and then, you can cast the ToString.